# How to run tests from HPQC in a distributed environment to make the device testing possible?

Tags: hp-quality-center

How to run tests from HPQC in a distributed environment to make the device testing possible?

I would like to invoke a test script on another machine from HPQC to make the devive testing possible. Please advise.